# Chrome devtools console refuses to evaluate anything

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, redux, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

Normally when you enter something like `1+1` into the Chrome console, it will do two things:

- echo your expression back to you
- display the result of evaluating the expression

This is why, when you enter `var x = 1` into the console you see two lines added to the console:

- `> var x = 1`
- `<- undefined`

because this `var` assignment evaluates to `undefined`.

I am developing a webapp with react / redux and recently I tried to evaluate something in the console (`1 + 1`).  To my absolute shock-horror, the console *refused* me!  I **did** see my statement echoed back to me, but I **did not** see the result.

Entering multiple things (random gibberish interspersed with `Enter` keypresses) shows that everything is **echoed** back, but nothing is **evaluated** (ie: I see no `undefined`s or `ReferenceError`s when throwing random strings at the console).

1. The console works fine in other tabs within the same window.
2. My application works as expected.
3. My application is built using [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux)
4. I am running my application locally using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)
5. I am using hot updates with [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) and the webpack [HotModuleReplacementPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#hotmodulereplacementplugin)
6. I continue to see XHRs logged to the console by various things my application is doing.
7. I can still see `console.log` messages generated by my application.

I ran the CPU profiler (in devtools -> Profiles tab) for a while and clicked around the app a bit - the profiler showed no unusual activity (eg lockups), just the expected behaviour while using my app.

What could cause Chrome devtools console to ignore direct input?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens where there's an unterminated string or loop in the console. Try "' )}

I've also recently had another, similar problem (although I didn't even get the echoes). There were statements from (IIRC) the redux-logger or -debugger in the console. These were collapsed and actually swallowing my output. Clicking the 'reveal' triangle showed my input / results.

Comment: Damn... I'm not seeing anything at all :(

Comment: Okay, one more idea: this usually happens where there's an unterminated string or loop in the console. Try "' )}

Comment: Ah-ha!  That appears to have fixed it... very weird.  Put that in your answer and I'll tick it - thanks :)